# How to get current hovered position with overlapping div?

Tags: javascript

Output:

[image]

Check blow for the sample code.

```js
function changeTo(i, e) {

  let DOMHover = document.getElementById('div-hover').getBoundingClientRect();
  document.getElementById('div-hover').style.display = 'block';

  let boundaryLeft = document.getElementById('product-listing-container-grid').offsetLeft;
  let boundaryTop = document.getElementById('product-listing-container-grid').offsetTop;
  let boundaryRight = document.getElementById('product-listing-container-grid').offsetLeft + document.getElementById('product-listing-container-grid').offsetWidth;
  let boundaryBottom = document.getElementById('product-listing-container-grid').offsetTop + document.getElementById('product-listing-container-grid').offsetHeight;
  let setLeft = (i.offsetLeft - (DOMHover.width / 3));
  let setTop = (i.offsetTop - (DOMHover.height / 3));
  if (boundaryLeft > setLeft) {
    setLeft = boundaryLeft;
  }
  if (boundaryTop > setTop) {
    setTop = boundaryTop;
  }
  if (boundaryRight < (setLeft + DOMHover.width)) {
    setLeft = boundaryRight - DOMHover.width;
  }
  if (boundaryBottom < (setTop + DOMHover.height)) {
    setTop = boundaryBottom - DOMHover.height;
  }
  document.getElementById('div-hover').style.left = setLeft + 'px';
  document.getElementById('div-hover').style.top = setTop + 'px';

  for (let _i = 0; _i < 3; _i ++) {
    for (let _j = 0; _j < 3; _j ++) {
      try {
        let current = document.elementFromPoint((DOMHover.x + (_i * DOMHover.width / 3) + 3), (DOMHover.y + (_j * DOMHover.height / 3) + 3)).closest('.product');
        // RETURNS WRONG ELEMENTS HERE
        console.log(current);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="product-listing-container-grid">
  <div id="div-hover" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 70%); position: absolute; z-index: 1; display: none; border: 3px solid #000;"></div>
  <ul class="product-grid">
    <li class="product" onmouseover="changeTo(this, event)">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=1" />
    </li>
    <li class="product" onmouseover="changeTo(this, event)">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=2" />
    </li>
    <li class="product" onmouseover="changeTo(this, event)">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=3" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The white box with border will hover on list and i want covered list.

When i am hover to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 list boxes (states) it returns the output as 4 but not 5 because of mouse pointer is on the `div-hover` and `product-listing-container-grid` is below the `div-hover`.

It is returns previous last coordinates/state/box.

How to get 5 means exact current position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting CSS:

```
#div-hover {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```